# Use john to crack passwords with X alphanums and Y symbols

Tags: passwords, john-the-ripper

I'd like to use john to crack passwords that has 3 chars and 1 symbol in it, e.g `123$`

If I use mask mode I will have to specify it 3 times,

```
-mask='[a-z0-9]?s[a-z0-9][a-z0-9]'
-mask='[a-z0-9][a-z0-9]?s[a-z0-9]'
-mask='[a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9]?s'
```

Is there anything better than this?

Answer (score 1):

The logic of masks does not allow for this. If you want only a certain number of a certain character set in more than one position, then you have to permute the options yourself, either by what you have done or by creating a wordlist.

Comment: And using multiple masks is faster (more compatible with running efficiently on GPU) than creating a wordlist, all other things being equal - and the faster the hash, the greater the difference. If the hash is slow enough, it doesn't make much difference. So preferring the multiple-mask method is good general advice.